# How to set srcObject on audio element with React

Tags: reactjs, web-audio-api

I've been trying to set the `src` attribute of an audio tag in React, but the track never plays.

```
playTrack(track) {
    const stream = new MediaStream()
    stream.addTrack(track)
    this.setState(() => ({ stream }))
}

render() {
    return (
        <audio src={this.state.stream || null} controls volume="true" autoPlay />
    )
}
```

When I check in the chrome debugger it shows that the audio tag has `[MediaStream]` set as its source, but nothing plays and all the controls remained grayed out.

Doing this instead of setting the state works, but I presume this is highly frowned upon in React.

```
const audio = document.querySelector('audio')
audio.srcObject = stream
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If storing the stream in the state is not a requirement, then you can update the `srcObject` property using a `ref`:

```
playTrack(track) {
    const stream = new MediaStream()
    stream.addTrack(track)
    this.audio.srcObject = stream;
}

render() {
    return (
        <audio ref={audio => {this.audio = audio}} controls volume="true" autoPlay />
    )
}
```

If you do need to access the stream from the state you can try this

```
<audio ref={audio => { audio.srcObject = this.state.stream }} />
```

The reason `src={this.state.stream}` doesn't work is because `src` expects a string that represents the url of the audio resource while `this.state.stream` is a `MediaStream` object.

`audio.src` and `audio.srcObject` are different properties that expect different value types.

Comment: I get audio is null when using ur example, am i suppose to define audio somewhere else before using as a ref?

Comment: @AJ_ probably on constructor you need `this.audio = React.createRef();` ?

Comment: Yeah, that was it.

Comment: what if i have array of stream and using that array i have to create audia tag?

Answer (score 7):

For those who use props and don't like to create function on each render:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.videoRef = React.createRef()
}

render() {
  return <video ref={this.videoRef}/>
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.updateVideoStream()    
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.updateVideoStream()
}

updateVideoStream() {
  if (this.videoRef.current.srcObject !== this.props.stream) {
    this.videoRef.current.srcObject = this.props.stream
  }
}
```