# How to use srcObject in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native web:

React-Native-Web: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

for the same I have to use Video tag.  I have created a video component using CreateElement.

This is the video component

```
import { createElement } from "react-native-web";

const Video = (props) => {
  const attrs = {
    srcObject: props.source,
    poster: props.poster,
    controls: "controls"
  }
  return createElement("video", attrs)
}
export default Video
```

and in component i am using it like this

```
<Video
  source={this.state.stream}  //this is media stream object
  poster={'https://www.fillmurray.com/480/300'}
/>
```

But above code is giving me error.How can I solve this?

> Warning: React does not recognize the `srcObject` prop on a DOM
>   element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
>   attribute, spell it as lowercase `srcobject` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element.

If i replace srcObject to lower case "srcobject" in Video component then i get below code and video doesnot play.

```
<video srcobject="[object MediaStream]" controls=""></video>
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: @jmkmay i added error and comment.

Comment: Really not into react and even less into react-native, but would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603402/how-to-set-srcobject-on-audio-element-with-react/48603493#48603493) help? And if curious [some discussion about the issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11163).

Comment: @Kaiido I am also new to React . The solution you shared I have tried already it is not working for React-Native.